# Getting 'fatal: error when closing sha1 file: Permission denied' after interrupting git commit

Tags: git

I was doing a commit in a local repository which was taking longer than I was expecting, I realized that I was committing a recently added large file so I decided to cancel by doing Ctrl-C.

I proceeded to add the large file to .gitignore and tried doing `git add` and `git commit` again.

The first time I tried I got an error indicating that index.lock existed, so I removed it manually. After `git add` I tried `git commit` but now I get the `fatal: error when closing sha1 file: Permission denied`

Is there something else I need to manually remove before being able to perform commits again?

Answer (score 1):

It can depends on your OS and Git version ([Git 2.19+, for instance, changes the way it deals with lock files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50275501/6309))

But if nothing else work, try and clone your repo again, to report your current modification on it, then add and commit from the new cloned repo.

Comment: I ended up re cloning and adding the modifications, I looked for an easier fix but at the end it did not take so much time to do this.

Comment: @dugar OK. I mentioned that option as a practical way to move forward, but I agree it is not the easiest solution.